# .filter() then apply only to certain .children()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Can't seem to figure this one out, feel like I'm missing something silly here...

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Dz7jN/)**

Basically, when **hovering** over the *remove link*, I'm trying to do a *line-through* on all text in that row, EXCEPT for the `<td>` with that `<a class="remove">` in it.

The basic html structure is:

```
<tr>
    <td>Lorem ipsum text here</td>
    <td>01/01/2012</td>
    <!-- all <td>'s except for the Remove one should get a line-through -->
    <td><a class="remove">Remove</a></td>
</tr>
```

jQuery:

```
$('tr').on({
    'mouseover' : function () {
        $(this).closest('tr').find('td').filter(function () {
            var $childElems = $(this).children();

            // I can see the <a class="remove"> in .children()
            // But for some reason can't just test (hey there's an <a>, 
            // then don't apply this)

            if ($childElems.find('a').length <= 0) {
                return $(this).css('text-decoration', 'line-through');
            }
        });
    },
    'mouseout' : function () {
        $(this).closest('tr').find('td')
            .css('text-decoration', 'none');
    }
}, 'a.remove');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the `filter()`, `this` is each of the `td` elements in turn. When you call `children()`on this, you get back a jQuery object *which is the `<a>`*, then, you're searching *within* that `<a>` for *another* `<a>` (which is why you're not seeing it).

Instead:

```
    $(this).closest('tr').find('td').filter(function () {
        if ($(this).children('a').length == 0) {
            return $(this).css('text-decoration', 'line-through');
        }
    });
```

... but that's not really what `filter` was designed for. You're supposed to use `filter` to reduce the set of elements, and then operate on the result:

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('td').filter(function () {
    return !$(this).children('a').length;
}).css('text-decoration', 'line-through');
```

Comment: Ahh haven't used `.filter()` much, supposed I was thinking of it all wrong! Thanks Matt, clears it right up.

Answer (score 3):

This would be a lot easier if you did not manipulate CSS properties directly, but used a class for that.

Add that class to your `tr` element on hover, and format the `td` using the descendant selector:

```
tr.highlighted td { text-decoration:line-through; }
tr.highlighted td:last-child { text-decoration:none; }
```

Comment: +1 definitely a good idea, unfortunately our main users are IE7 & 8, forced to use JS for the dumbest situations haha

Comment: I’m not saying do it with `:hover`, but apply the class to the `tr` element with jQuery. And if `:last-child` is your main concern – that could be avoided if the last `td` got a class in the HTML code as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('tr').on({
    'mouseover' : function () {
        $(this).closest('tr').find('td').each(function () {
            if($(this).find('a.remove').length == 0){
                $(this).css('text-decoration', 'line-through');
            }
        });
    },
    'mouseout' : function () {
        $(this).closest('tr').find('td').css('text-decoration', 'none');
    }
}, 'a.remove');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a.remove').hover(function () {
    $(this).parents('tr').find('td').filter(function () {
        return !$(this).find('a.remove').length;
    }).css('text-decoration', 'line-through');
}, function () {
    $(this).parents('tr').find('td').css('text-decoration', 'none');
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Dz7jN/2/)**